# Android UI design pattern to exploit existing UI

Tags: android

I have an application that consists of several UI but each one must use a basic similar interface to add it a new components.I'm looking for if there is a design pattern to applied, I tried to use the decorator but its not working.

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of template to help you keep consistence over all your UI elements?

Comment: I'm Looking for how to use a basic UI that brings together common elements of all other UI and each UI can add these features, such as the principle of inheritance a base class which inherits the girls to add the new features .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to take a look to guidelines provided by Android developer team: **[Android design patterns guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/index.html)**

*[Action bar](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html)* and *[Navigation drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)* are the most used (and suggested) design patterns which `"brings together common elements of all other UI"`, as you asked. Each activity of your app can interact with them, adding/removing/listening to elements in it.

In order to properly implement these UI design patterns, you should already know how to use fragments. If not, please check [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html) out.